# Id from AutoComplete TextView

Tags: android, android-activity, autocompletetextview

I am getting a list of names with ids from API.
I am populating the names in an AutoCompleteTextView. But I want to get the corresponding ids also that are coming from API.
Anyway to do it?

Comment: @pskink from server.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830), then replace `c.newRow().add(i)` with `c.newRow().add(itemId)` where `itemId` comes from your API

Comment: ya but, again I need just the id of the item that the user has selected. If I do getTex(), I will get everything

Comment: you have `long id` parameter in `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick`

Comment: You can take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047156/how-to-create-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextview) for reference. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best and the most modular approach to do this is by storing all the information regarding your selected item in a **java model class**. This way you will get all the information in a **single java object** and you can then use its getter methods to get the corresponding id. [Here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) is an online tool to convert your json into a corresponding java setter and getter class.